# What can cause an application to be available for sale elsewhere and not in the USA?

Tags: app-store-connect

I've an application and it's language is english. I am not in US. I changed my iTunes app store to U.S for looking at the apps in the U.S Store... I trying to access my app but I'm getting this:

[image]

But my app is downloaded in U.S and other many countries in the world. I am a little confused. M*y App really isn't available in the U.S Store? Then how it is downloaded in U.S? How can I see which stores sell my app?*

Comment: Why wouldn't you log into iTunes connect and just look at the provisioning for the app in question? There are many reasons why an app isn't for sale at a particular moment, but rather than have us guess, you could know.

Comment: @bmike I dont know where should I look in iTunes connect? I can't see anything about the appstore countries in iTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to review the regional settings for that SKU by logging into iTunes Connect.

This is documented at Apple's [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html)

Scroll down to the part where it describes the following:

> Setting Territory Rights, Pricing and Availability
>
> On this page, you:
>
> - Set the date when you want your app to go live on the App Store
> - Schedule price tier changes for the future (by setting a price tier effective date and a price tier end date)
> - (iOS only) Offer a discount to educational institutions buying in bulk
> - Select the territories where you would like to make your app available (do nothing to have your app available worldwide)
>
> If you need assistance as you’re filling out the page, select the
>   appropriate Help button (?) next to the field or refer to Table 7-2
>   for the property descriptions. You can modify these settings at any
>   time, including after the app is available on the App Store.

Also, before calling for help, be sure you didn't remove it from sale by setting a future availability date for that SKU:

> **Important**: Your app’s availability date ultimately determines if your app is live on the App Store or not. If your availability date is
>   set to a date in the future, even if your app is Ready for Sale, it
>   will not be live in the App Store until your availability date
>   approaches.

I would assume there's a problem with your account in the case where you can't fix this immediately or the help doesn't work. In that instance, contact Apple directly at [Developer Support for iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/itunes-connect/)

Comment: thank you very much.. I've found this line in my Itunes connect: "Unless you select specific stores, your app will be for sale in all App Stores worldwide." I guess something wrong with my iTunes application on my desktop.